# Java 6 Content-type return wrong type on App Ionic

Tags: java, angular, cordova, ionic3

I'm developing an rest api on java 6 because on my work are using Tomcat 6. I have de api point working on Postman but when I try to use it on my Ionic app it returns a wrong type(html instead of json).

[image]

Note that any header is supplied

On my Ionic App

[image]

Here I'm using the next code:

```
getPosData():Observable<any>{

let url = this.isProd ? this.urlBaseProd : this.urlBase;
url += "pos/getposall";   

return this.httpClient.get(url);
}
```

This is my controller

[image]

and a generic response class.

[image]

My ionic info

✔ Gathering environment info - done!

Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.2.1 (/home/usuario/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.2
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.2.0, (and 8 other plugins)

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/usuario/Android/Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v8.12.0 (/usr/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : Linux 4.15

Comment: I have tested on a ionic app blank just with HttpClient and It's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was debbuging I have noticed that `ionic cordova run android` let app working on localhost:8080 and my war is on the same place. So I decided to deploy my war on pre-production server and all works fine.